# Unusual triangular pinned security screw

Tags: screws, security

Does anyone recognise this security screw? Found in South West England on a playground gate.

[image: screw]

Comment: It is new to me also, so went to google.  Seems like there many different designs, more than what us common folk would think are needed.

Comment: Maybe it's one of the variants of the [Ultra-Drive Security Machine Screw](https://www.fastenright.com/security-fasteners/ultra-drive-security-machine-screws/ul01). Apparently the exact hole design is unique to each customer.

Comment: Can you give us a zoomed out picture of what it is that screw is mounted to? :)

Comment: The right sized flat head ought to get that out.  Or a cold chisel.  Or a drill.

Comment: Prefer an angle grinder with a thin blade.  Cuts heads off in no time, leaves a nice flat end if need to drill out the body.

Comment: Me, an old flat head from the box, ground to fit…

Comment: It reminds me of screws used to secure access hatches in street lights, although those are a bit bigger.

Comment: Reminds me of a phone conversation, back when I used to see things like that on a daily basis…"Guys, you know those fancy new screws you just spent a fortune on? Did you know you can just use a 4mm security hex?" ….Long silence ensued...

Comment: Yeah, in a pinch you can also defeat torx screws with an appropriately wide flat head :) Although in both cases damage will probably ensue to the screw (or screwdriver, or both) if done repeatedly. The OP's screw is not a difficult shape anyway, you can always fabricate something that fits from a steel rod. Just need to file down the sides, then drill a straight hole in the middle. Can even give the other end a hexagonal pattern for drill bit like ease of use.

Comment: …and another thing - if the steel is brittle enough, you can snap out the security pin ;)) Just bend one way, then back again should be enough. Then a screwdriver or non-security hex will fit.

Comment: Also, once out, replace with screws with a normal (slot, philips, hex or torx) head.

Comment: This is on a playground gate. I'm not going to destructively remove it! I was just curious.

Comment: @andrewmorton Yeah I had a look before posting and that was the closest I could find too. Seems like the most likely option.

Comment: @Timmmm In that case, I made an answer from my comment.

Comment: Upvote because of clear picture and a thing that I have never heard of.  Individualized screws!

Comment: @Willk Before [Joseph Whitworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Whitworth) every [screw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Standard_Whitworth) was individual.

Comment: Damned Old Joe stealing our individuality... *shakes fist*

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be one of the variants of the [Ultra-Drive Security Machine Screw](https://www.fastenright.com/security-fasteners/ultra-drive-security-machine-screws/ul01).

Apparently the exact hole design is unique to each customer, and correlating to your comment that they were found in SW England, made by the U.K. company Fastenright Limited (no connection to me).